# How to install Eclipse Market Place in RAD 9

Tags: eclipse, rad

By Default, RAD doesn't have the eclipse marketplace. How to install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For RAD,Version 9.0.0:

Try to install using the .

Go to help->install software - Click on "Add".

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Select "General Purpose Tools / Marketplace Client"

Then  "Next - Finish"

Comment: This answer worked great for me. I had an older update link before that caused a bunch of errors. You have to use the update link matching your version of RAD